# Cert-Manager Kubernetes order stuck on Pending

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, lets-encrypt, cert-manager

Objects below, this worked fine getting a staging cert from Let's Encrypt, but now that I've cut over to prod it does not work and is hanging for >12hrs

The public IP *is* the correct one (I can navigate to it via https://website.gg and get the expected cert errors, same with ping etc.)

All subdomains are correctly routed to this same public/external IP

CertificateIssuer has been hanging for 12 hours and seems to have no chance to resolve.

Relevant objects:

Certificate:

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha3
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2022-01-21T06:01:42Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  name: mysecret-tls
  namespace: mine
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    controller: true
    kind: Ingress
    name: mine-api-ingress
    uid: fbbfdbac-5480-469e-8230-6d018d5ef151
  resourceVersion: "11962900"
  uid: 2710c043-7f95-4576-982f-03b702038105
spec:
  dnsNames:
  - website.gg
  - '*.website.gg'
  issuerRef:
    group: cert-manager.io
    kind: ClusterIssuer
    name: letsencrypt-prod
  secretName: mysecret-tls
status:
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2022-01-21T06:01:42Z"
    message: Waiting for CertificateRequest "mysecret-tls-3406177836" to complete
    reason: InProgress
    status: "False"
    type: Ready
```

ClusterIssuer:

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha3
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: mine-api
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
  creationTimestamp: "2022-01-17T03:43:44Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  name: letsencrypt-prod
  resourceVersion: "10876278"
  uid: 27b34bfe-16e7-4d51-9229-ad12abb52df6
spec:
  acme:
    email: myemail@email.com
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-prod
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress:
          class: nginx
status:
  acme:
    lastRegisteredEmail: myemail@email.com
    uri: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/acct/367378310
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2022-01-17T03:43:44Z"
    message: The ACME account was registered with the ACME server
    reason: ACMEAccountRegistered
    status: "True"
    type: Ready
```

CertificateRequest:

```
  Issuer Ref:
    Group:  cert-manager.io
    Kind:   ClusterIssuer
    Name:   letsencrypt-prod
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2022-01-21T06:01:44Z
    Message:               Waiting on certificate issuance from order mine/mysecret-tls-3406177836-1310394537: "pending"
    Reason:                Pending
    Status:                False
    Type:                  Ready
Events:                    <none>
```

Ingress:

```
...
metadata:
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
...    

spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: mine-api-service
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /api/(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
      - backend:
          service:
            name: mine-bot-service
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /bot/(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
      - backend:
          service:
            name: mine-ui-service
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - website.gg
    - '*.website.gg'
    secretName: mysecret-tls
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - hostname: a605c42f1adc44435bb1cab34ee9bf3a
      ip: {my-public-ip}
```

Comment: Can you provide logs from order and challenge?